# Why e.Row.Cells[2].Text always show "" or null in GridView1_RowDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        // DataRow data = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        string ToolTipString = Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
        e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes.Add("title", ToolTipString);
        Label MyLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("MyLabel");

        if (ToolTipString.Length < 20) {
            MyLabel.Text = ToolTipString;
        }
        else {
            MyLabel.Text = String.Format("{0}...", ToolTipString.Substring(0, 17));
            MyLabel.ToolTip = ToolTipString;
        }
    }
}
```

But `Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);` here always gives me "". Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use this code

```
var ToolTipString = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Column"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but here column is columnname and in my code how i get columnname for that perticular cell in loop

Comment: use :((DataBoundLiteralControl)e.Row.Cells[7].Controls[0]).Text;

Comment: sorry but its not working is there any other to find cell text value in loop e.row.cells.count

Comment: my problam is solve now i use string colname = gcQueryResult0.Columns(i).SortExpression/HeaderText; to get the column name thanks to "@Shahrooz Jefri"

Answer (score 2):

Usually this problem happens when the Column is hidden on the Grid. Two steps to solve it,

1. Instead of using    Visible="false" use a css class for the bound field like this,    ItemStyle-CssClass="Column_Hide"
2. Create Column_Hide in css file,

   ```
   .Column_Hide
    {
       display: none;
    }
   ```

Hopefully your problem will be solved